# SQL JOIN with Team Names from teams table in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to show team name in Match Schedule,  I am using below query but it gets me both TeamA & TeamB as same name

```
SELECT m.ID AS MID,  MatchDate,  
t.Name AS TeamName, 'v' AS VS,  
t.Name AS TeamName, Group
  FROM Matches m 
JOIN Team T ON  m.TeamA_ID = t.Id 
JOIN  Team T2 ON m.TeamB_ID = t2.Id
```

How can i get Correct team name based on TeamA_ID, TeamB_ID

**Table Team**

```
ID
TeamName
TeamCountry
```

**Table Matches**

```
ID
MatchDate
TeamA_ID
TeamB_ID
Location
Group


ID      TeamName        TeamCountry
1       TeamOne         100
2       TeamTwo         30
3       TeamThree       80
4       TeamFour        90
5       TeamFive        98
6       TeamSix         99
7       TeamSeven       200
8       TeamEight       14


ID      MatchDate       TeamA_ID    TeamB_ID    Location    Group
1       01-01-2019      2           4           L1          A
2       02-01-2019      6           1           L1          A
3       04-01-2019      5           8           L1          B
4       06-01-2019      2           6           L1          B
5       10-01-2019      3           4           L1          C
6       16-01-2019      5           6           L1          C
```

I want result as

```
ID      Date            TeamName        vs      TeamName    Location    Group
1       01-01-2019      TeamTwo         v       TeamFour        L1          A
2       02-01-2019      TeamSix         v       TeamOne         L1          A
3       04-01-2019      TeamFive        v       TeamEight       L1          B
4       06-01-2019      TeamTwo         v       TeamSix         L1          B
5       10-01-2019      TeamThree       v       TeamFour        L1          C
6       16-01-2019      TeamFive        v       TeamSix         L1          C
```

Comment: just a typo. use `t2.` instead of `t.` on second team name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you almost got it.

```
SELECT  m.ID AS MID,  
        MatchDate,  
        T.Name AS TeamName, 
        'v' AS VS,  
        T2.Name AS TeamName, -- Should be T2.Name
        Group
FROM   Matches m 
JOIN   Team T ON  m.TeamA_ID = T.Id 
JOIN   Team T2 ON m.TeamB_ID = T2.Id
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple mistake (you have `t.Name` twice instead of `t2.Name` and `t.Name`)

```
SELECT m.ID AS MID,  MatchDate,  
    t.Name AS TeamName,
    t2.Name AS TeamName,
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In your select you are selecting t.Name twice, change the second one to t2.Name.

```
    SELECT m.ID AS MID,  MatchDate,  
t.Name AS TeamName, 'v' AS VS,  
t2.Name AS TeamName, Group
  FROM Matches m 
JOIN Team T ON  m.TeamA_ID = t.Id 
JOIN  Team T2 ON m.TeamB_ID = t2.Id
```

Comment: Thanks, Went unnoticed and waited 30 minutes as i was not able to see small type/mistake..

Comment: Yeah, we've all experienced it. You look at your mistakes but can see it. Happy coding